# MongoDB in Python Anaconda

Tags: python, mongodb, anaconda

I am trying to setup MongoDB on an Anaconda Python environment.  While in the conda environment I ran `conda install -c anaconda mongodb=2.4.6` but once i try to run the command `service mongodb start` the command cannot be found.  Also when I run `mongod` I get something about `/data/db`path does not exist for the dpath.  How does MongoDB on Anaconda work? Did I install it correctly?

I am running on osx 10.11.

`mongod` command outputs:

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6765 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=Roberts-MBP
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] 
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx-106-x86-64-2.10gen.cc 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:32:41 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Sun May  8 19:08:00.893 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296 
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 dbexit: 
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun May  8 19:08:00.895 dbexit: really exiting now`
```

`sudo service mongodb start` command outputs:

```
-bash: service: command not found
```

And here are additional errors when I try running pymongo within anaconda python environment.  I tried to create a database, and return the name of the new database, but returned an error.

```
>>> import  pymongo
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> client.database_names()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1027, in database_names
    "listDatabases")["databases"]]
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 478, in command
    with client._socket_for_reads(read_preference) as (sock_info, slave_ok):
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 752, in _socket_for_reads
    with self._get_socket(read_preference) as sock_info:
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 716, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 142, in select_server
    address))
  File "//anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 118, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: What are the exact errors for `sudo service mongod start` and `mondod`? What platform are you on (Linux, OSX, Windows?)

Comment: sorry about that. added some more info, hopefully that gives a better picture of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operative error here is `ERROR: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist.` Simply do `sudo mkdir /data/db` and try running `mongod` again - should work.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I am trying to insall Mongodb on a virtual environment such as anaconda. Would I still create the directory under the root directory?

Comment: You can create it whereever you want - if you want to create it somewhere else you can do that, then you have to specify the directory when launching `mongod`, like this: `mongod --dbpath /path/to/my/custom/dir`.

Comment: By adding it seem to make pymongo work now, but I have to have a terminal open with an open mongo connection, is this the norm?

Comment: Yep. You can run it in the background by running `mongod &`, and then it won't take up a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the /data/db path first

Try running the following lines of code in your terminal:

```
sudo bash
mkdir -p /data/db
chmod 777 /data
chmod 777 /data/db
```

To make sure the code you just enters works, enter the following in the terminal:

```
ls -ld /data/db
```

You should see the following output:

drwxrwxrwx  2 root  wheel  68 Mar 28 11:05 /data/db

For more information or clarification on the steps watch the [MongoDB install video for Mac](https://youtu.be/_WJ8m5QHvwc)

Comment: 777 is not advaisable 755 should do the trick. Moreover, you might not have problems with permissions, but ownership. "sudo chown $USER /data/db" fixed it for me.